# How to get percentages value of predicted object In Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used this [code](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/Object_detection_image.py) to display object detector with percentage of predicted value, but the variable `num_detections` is a `TensorVariable` such as `Tensor("num_detections:0", dtype=float32)`. So how can I print the percentage of predicted value?

Before you comment, I know there is a similar question but the answer does not seem to work. It prints `Tensor("truediv:0", dtype=float32)` and I want the percentages.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to evaluate that tensor `num_detections` in the created `session` by calling `sess.run`. The code you linked actually did that for you.

```
# Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})
```

So you could simply print out the value of `num`.

Comment: if I do that It just prints '[200.]'

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by " the percentages value of predicted object "? Is it the prediction `scores`?

Comment: Like when I turn it on, It shows the object with the value of predicted object for example 99% I want to print that, i can add a photo if it would help

Comment: I think that is the `scores`. Do you want to print out the one named `scores` inside this 4-tuple `(boxes, scores, classes, num)`?

Comment: I did but when I printed it it showed me 2d arrays with numbers I'm thinking maybe its pixels and I need to sum them up to get to 99% but I dont know how.

Comment: If you look at this line https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/Object_detection_image.py#L81, it says very clear "# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label." Since you said the `num_detections` is 200, you would get an array with length 200, the `scores` are paired with `classes`.